Error trying to use react-native-chart-kit
I have this error every time I install react-native-chart-kit using expo and try to run the server
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGRect, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
I checked ls react-native-svg and it seams that the chat kit packet install another version
+-- react-native-chart-kit@6.12.0
| `-- react-native-svg@15.2.0 deduped
+-- react-native-gradient-texts@0.1.0
| `-- react-native-svg@13.14.1
`-- react-native-svg@15.2.0

This is because each package uses a different version of react-native-svg. Therefore you are trying to register more than one view. Instead of installing it as a dependency install it as a resolution.
You need to add it into your resolution in package.json:
"resolutions": {
  "react-native-svg": "15.2.0"
},

and delete the line ”react-native-svg": "15.2.0" at dependencies.
This will force your other dependencies to use react-native-svg 15.2.0
